# Are questions about where heat losses go on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Okay, I'm curious if a question *related to heat losses* is on on topic here. It'd be better to show you what I was going to post than to explain it, so this is what it will be:

> **How is the heat lost in a peltier distributed?**
>
> I'm looking at peltier elements to heat my project. I seem to find that most are
>   about 5% efficient, but how is the 95% turned into heat distributed?
>
> Does the cold side get 47.5% and the warm side get 52.5% of the
>   energy, or is it more complex depending on the difference between the
>   temperatures?

My first thought is, *"It should be OK since on EE they talk about heat losses ALL the time!"* However, after thinking about this, it seems like it might be too much thermodynamics to be on EE. Is this on topic here or should I ask on another SE site?

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be fine. It looks more like a thermoelectric device behavior question and still "feels" related to electronics.